# Add two pipeline values together

Tags: powershell, winapi, math, processor

How can I add the result of the following command together to get `20` as output instead of 2x `10`?

```
gwmi Win32_processor -ComputerName SomeComputer | select-object -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Measure-Object` cmdlet with the `-Sum` switch:

```
gwmi Win32_processor -ComputerName SomeComputer |
     select-object -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores | 
     Measure-Object -Sum | 
     select -ExpandProperty Sum
```

---

Or if you want a hacky solution:

```
iex ((gwmi Win32_processor -ComputerName SomeComputer | 
    select-object -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores) -join '+')
```

This basically joins all numbers with a `+` to a string and then invokes that expression.